# Javascript dynamic checkbox values as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I currently have a json file that contains the inventory of vehicles.  I have a search page that allows the users to filter the inventory using checkboxes, such as make, model, color, etc..

I need to pass the checkbox values as an array.  For example, if I select Mustang and Camaro checkboxes, it would need to be `'Model' => ['Mustang', 'Camaro']`.

I tried to create 2 arrays.  One for the keys, (Make, Model, Color), etc... and another for each of the values, (Mustang and Camaro).  Some values may have one item, some may have several.  For example, if we wanted all red Mustang's and Camaro's, the array should look like:

```
['Model' => ['Mustang', 'Camaro'],Color' => ['Red']];
```

Or, just red Mustangs:

```
['Model' => ['Mustang'],Color' => ['Red']];
```

I can loop each of the checkboxes, and I attempted to put all the checkbox names (data.id) as a key, and a second array (data.value) as the values.  If the key exists, then add each of the values that have the same key.

```
var kv=[]; // Keys
var vv=[]; // Array of the values for each key.

$("[name='checkBoxItem']").each(function (index, data) {
   if (data.checked) {
          if(!(data.id in kv)){  // Is always called.
               alert("Does't exist, adding : " + data.value);
               kv.push(data.id);
               vv.push(data.value);
                  } else {
                    vv.push(data.value);
                  }
              checked.push({[kv]: vv});
            }
        });
```

My code returns:

```
Array ( [selected_values] => Array([0] => Array ([Make] => Array([0] => Mustang))))
```

Which is close, but `if(!(data.id in kv))` is always being called, preventing me from adding multiple selections.

I am sorry if I am having coders block on something that I should have been able to do.

Comment: Using `in` for array is incorrect for checking elements within the array. `in` looks for keys and array keys are same as indexing. `0 in [3]// true` but `3 in [3]//false`. Try `if( !kv.includes(data.id))`

Comment: I tried changing the code as you suggested, however using:

if( !kv.includes(data.id)) {
kv.push(data.id); }

always executes, even when the data.id is the same on the next loop iteration.
Thanks again for the quick response.  I probably have another logic error on how this should be done.  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Yes that will solve the if() working properly. To be honest you are mixing javascript and php syntax for the `$filters` and not sure how you pass that from php to javascript

Comment: Sorry, but that is correct. The if is working properly. The array is always empty the first run, triggering the doesn't exist alert. I need to generate the array in a way that populates the arrays, and identifies duplicate keys in the process.  If the duplicate key exists, then add the another value to that  array.  For example, add Model = Mustang, next occurrence of Model, Model = Mustang, Camaro.

Comment: Would really help to show how you pass the php array to javascript

Comment: Thanks, sorry but the php array is not passed to javascript.  There are checkboxes that are generated from the available inventory from a json file.  The file contains vehicles of various makes and models.   For example, if the json contains Ford, Chevy and VW, then there are checkboxes for Make that contains a checkbox for Ford, Chevy and VW.  I loop over all the selected checkboxes to create an array.  If Ford and Chevy are selected, I would like to have a javascript array that is Model:Ford,Chevy.  That array is passed to the php page that does the filter for display using ajax Post data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery in your example I assume is not a problem to use it also to retrieve the actual data-values, therefore I'll use it in my example :)

You can find here a working example where you have a bunch of checkboxes and a button to collect the checkboxes values.

```js
$("#getvalues").on("click", function() {
  var result = {};
  $("input").each(function(index, el) {
    if (el.checked) {
      var id = $(el).data("id");
      var val = $(el).data("value");
      if (!result[id]) result[id] = [];
      result[id].push(val);
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-id="model" data-value="Camaro" >Camaro</input></br>
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="model" data-value="Mustang" >Mustang</input></br>
    Color</br>
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="color" data-value="Red" >Red</input></br>
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="color" data-value="Blue" >Blue</input></br>
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="color" data-value="Green" >Green</input></br>
    <button id="getvalues">
      GET SELECTED VALUES
    </button>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works for the 2 defined filters.  The only question is we do not know what they will check, so I cannot statically define the Model and Color array.  They may select Make, and Mileage.  Or Year, Color, Manual, and Convertible.   Do I loop the json and create that array, instead of defining it?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mike I've updated the code snippet according to your last request. Hope it helps

Comment: It does.  Thank you!